# How to make a pointer to call my member function?

Tags: c++

I have a member function "myfunction" and "my constraint1" as follows.

```
//f= k1(x1-a1)^2 + k2(x2-a2)^2 + k3(x3-a3)^2
double CNonlinearOptimization::myfunction(unsigned n, const double *x, double *grad, void *pdata) {

    if (grad) {
        grad[0] = 2*k1*(x[0]-1);
        grad[1] = 2*k2*(x[1]-3);
        grad[2] = 2*k3*(x[2]-5);
    }

    return (k1*(x[0]-1)*(x[0]-1)+k2*(x[1]-3)*(x[1]-3)+k3*(x[2]-5)*(x[2]-5));
}

double CNonlinearOptimization::myconstraint1(unsigned n, const double *x, double *grad, void *data){

    ++count;

    if (grad) {
        grad[0] = -1;       //grad[0] = d(c1)/dx1
        grad[1] = 0;        //grad[1] = d(c1)/dx2
        grad[2] = 0;        //grad[2] = d(c1)/dx3
    }
    return (0.9-(x[0]-2));
}
```

i will call its function by applying nlopt in main function like below.
`nlopt_set_min_objective(opt,nonlinopt.myfunction, NULL);
nlopt_add_inequality_constraint(opt,nonlinopt.myconstraint1, NULL, 1e-8);`

I tried to make a pointer:

```
CNonlinearOptimization nonlinopt;
nlopt_set_min_objective(opt,nonlinopt.myfunction, NULL);
```

But, I got some error:

```
NonlinearOptimization.cpp(288): error C3867: 'CNonlinearOptimization::myfunction': function call missing argument list; use '&CNonlinearOptimization::myfunction' to create a pointer to member
NonlinearOptimization.cpp(290): error C3867: 'CNonlinearOptimization::myconstraint1': function call missing argument list; use '&CNonlinearOptimization::myconstraint1' to create a pointer to member
```

Is anyone know how to solve it ?

Comment: Can you show us the ways that you've tried obtaining that pointer?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you should use

```
&objectName.memberFunctionName
```

syntax to obtain a pointer to member function. Note the `&`.
Try to pass it this way

```
nlopt_set_min_objective(opt, &nonlinopt.myfunction, NULL);
```